# Is it possible to have a function with non-global parameters?

Tags: packages, contexts

If I have functions in two packages that have parameters such as length_, width_ and height_; is there any way to have both packages loaded without generating messages such as "Symbol length appears in multiple contexts"?

Is there any way to make function parameters local instead of global?

Do all function names and parameters need to be unique across packages?

Comment: Please see the linked question on how to construct packages.  These name clashes will not happen when the standard package structure is followed.

Comment: Wait a second... I've never heard of function *parameter* names colliding, in any programming language. Is that something that actually happens in Mathematica packages??

Comment: @RahulNarain This happens when one does not use ``Private` `` sub-context for implementation code. Those symbols (local variables) are then generated in public context and exported as well, when the context is loaded.